# Looking for examples of ffmpeg and concat with list.txt and fade in-out

Tags: ffmpeg

I've been researching how to do an ffmpeg-concat with play list and fade in/out. I haven't seen an example of this combination. my current command is as follows: I'd like to fade in and out of each video clip, and there are 35-60 video clips in the .txt list. ffmpeg build is from 2016, so it doesn't have gltransition.

```
ffcommand = {"-f", "concat", "-safe", "0", "-i", renderDirPath + "concatscript.txt", "-i", musicDirPath, "-map", "0:v", "-map", "1:a", "-vf", "scale=640x480", renderDirPath + "finalrender.mp4"}
```

Comment: I've noticed that most answers with concat does not include a filelist.txt in the command, its always concatentation of fixed or handful of files, those filtercomplex formats do not work with a filelists. just not enough examples.

Comment: Closing this, I've decided to have multiple simple commands than a complex one, it takes longer, but it gets the job done.